# Matrix Invertibility- Verify Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

$$ \text{ if $A,B$ are invertible matrices, prove $AB$ is invertible } $$
$$ A, B \text{ invertible} \implies \text{ $A$ and $B$ are each the product of elementary matrices } E_{1} E_{2} \cdots E_{n}$$

$$ \text{ $A,B$ the product of elementary matrices} \implies AB \text{ is the product of elementary matrices} $$

$$ \text{since the product of elementary matrices is always invertible } \implies AB \text{ is invertible}$$

Comment: Actually it is true in any ring, so it reduces to ‘Show units in a ring are a multiplicative group’.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a perfectly acceptable solution, but how about:

$A, B$ invertible $\implies$ we can find $A^{-1},B^{-1}$ s.t. $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I = BB^{-1} = B^{-1}B$.  Then we see that $$AB(B^{-1}A^{-1}) = AIA^{-1} = AA^{-1} = I \implies B^{-1}A^{-1} = (AB)^{-1}$$ i.e. $AB$ is invertible.

Comment: very clean- nice

Answer (score 2):

First show that a square matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det (A)\neq 0$. Then consider $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)\neq 0$ and so $AB$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B$ are invertible matrices, let
$A^{-1}A=  B^{-1}B= I$, then

$$(B^{-1}A^{-1})(AB)=B^{-1}(A^{-1}A)B=B^{-1}(I)B =B^{-1}B =I$$

So $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$